# java, javascript signed applet (file choosing, ftp upload) security/socket exception

Tags: java, javascript, security, sockets

I've got a java applet that uses a class with 3 functions ( not counting test functions ):

- One for running file chooser and add selected files ( type FileContents ) to an array.
- Second to remove some of that files from array if necessary.
- Third one is for upload files to an ftp server.

  All of them are called from `Javascript` code. Two first functions works just fine.
  Upload function is not working, It throws:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" (dest. ftp server) "resolve")

Applet is self signed. I'm using `[Yii Framework][1]`. 
**Important code:- Uploader upload function:**

```
public void upload( String ftpServer, String username, String password, String filePath )
throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    if ( ftpServer != null && filePath != null && this.filesArray.length > 1 ) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
        //check for authentication, if username and password not provided assume annonymous access
        if ( username != null && password != null ) {
            sb.append( username );
            sb.append( ':' );
            sb.append( password );
            sb.append( '@' );
        }

        sb.append( ftpServer );
        sb.append( ":21" );
        sb.append( '/' );

        if ( !filePath.equals( "" ) ) {
            sb.append( filePath );
            sb.append( '/' );
        }

        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer( sb.toString() );
        //below: i < this.filesArray.length - 1 becouse last field is always empty
        for ( int i = 0; i < this.filesArray.length - 1; i++ ){ 
            sb.append( this.filesArray[ i ].getName() );
            sb.append( ";type=i" );

            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
                URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

                bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlConn.getOutputStream() );
                bis = new BufferedInputStream( this.filesArray[ i ].getInputStream() );

                int j;
                //read byte by byte until end of stream
                while ( ( j = bis.read() ) != -1 ) {
                    bos.write( j );
                }
            }
            finally {
                if ( bis != null ) {
                    try {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    catch( IOException ioe ) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if ( bos != null ) {
                    try {
                        bos.close();
                    }
                    catch ( IOException ioe ) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            sb = sb2;
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println( "Ftp address incorrect or input file not available." );
    }
}
```

**Deploy code**:

```
    <script>
var attributes = { id:'uploader1Applet',
    code: 'filesUpload.uploaderApplet',
    archive:'<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/java/uploaderApplet.jar',  width:1, height:1} ;


var parameters = {jnlp_href: '<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);?>/java/upload-applet.jnlp'};   


     deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6') ;
```

- **javascript declaration + initialization ( initialize only job is to assign new FileContents array to Uploader property; same view as above, different script ):**

> ```
> var uploader = document.getElementById( 'uploader1Applet' ).getUploader();
>       uploader.initialize();
> ```

- **upload method call ( same script as Uploader declaration + initialization) :**

> uploader.upload( connAddress, connUsername, '< ? php echo
>   Yii::app()->session[ 'ftpPassword' ]; ?>', connRootFolder != null ?
>   connRootFolder : "" );

Any ideas how to solve my problem ?

Comment: How did you signed the applet can you post those commands here?

Comment: (in place of keytool below: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/bin/./keytool ; same for jarsigner )

(1): keytool -genkey -keystore pKeyStore -alias me

(2): keytool -selfcert -keystore pKeyStore -alias me

(3): jarsigner -keystore pKeyStore ./uploaderApplet.jar me

Comment: PS. Ftp server is outside my hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Java methods called from Javascript typically need to be wrapped in an [`AccessController.doPrivileged(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method_summary) call, to be trusted.

Comment: But it seemed a bit dangerous for me. Besides, I tried that and I have no idea how to pass necessary parameters (connection parameters, files array ) to code wrapped in .doPrivileged().

Comment: There are examples at the top of the linked page.